# Is it possible to play GTA V on Xbox 360 with the first disc only?

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I recently bought *GTA V* for my Xbox 360. I received disc 1 and I still want to play but I don't want to pay for another disc. So my point is, is it possible to play without getting the second disc?

Answer (score 2):

No, you need both disks to play the game. The first disk installs the game and the second disk allows you to launch it and play. You could try purchasing the missing disk off eBay, or get another copy of the game with both disks in it.